# How to detect main sound direction from AVAudioSession

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiosession, avaudiorecorder

I want to detect the main direction of the sound recorded from iPhone. For example, I want to detect if the sound comes from "front" or "rear" camera.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosessiondatasourcedescription
This link describes how to set, but not how to detect in real time.

**UPDATE:**

Example use:
I start recording with front and back camera at the same time. I want to detect if audio comes from front o rear to change camera automaticatlly.

Is there any way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over `AVAudioSession.inputDataSources`, to check out available sources and obtain the one you want, and then set it to `AVAudioSession.setPreferredInput()`. If You don't need to set the input but just check it, use `AVAudioSession.currentRoute.inputs`

Comment: I just need to detect the direction, no need to set it

Comment: How did you go with this? I’m thinking of building something similar.